# Are RoomDb update/insert coroutine calls cancellable or will they complete regardless of cancellation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Are roomDb calls cancellable? i.e. suspend functions have to be using `yield()` or check `isActive()` in order to react to cancellation. I'm trying to decide if it's safe to depend on a small (or rather large) roomDb transaction update to go through even if the viewModelScope is cancelled before transaction is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancellation should be [cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative):

> Coroutine cancellation is cooperative. A coroutine code has to cooperate to be cancellable. All the suspending functions in `kotlinx.coroutines` are cancellable. They check for cancellation of coroutine and throw `CancellationException` when cancelled. However, if a coroutine is working in a computation and does not check for cancellation, then it cannot be cancelled.

Speaking of `Room` DB under the hood they use `withContext` to switch between contexts, `withContext` is cancellable, therefore we can conclude that the RoomDB suspend calls are cancellable.

To invoke suspend function in a non-cancellable fashion we can use `withContext(NonCancellable) {}` or create a global `CoroutineScope`, that will have an application lifetime, and use it to launch coroutines.

Comment: Thanks Sergio I completely forgot about the cooperative part, so I think as long as I made it inside withContext I won't have any issues. thank you.